# Replace element tag keep its children

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

Lets say i have this simple xml:

```
<root>
   <dad> 
     <kid> wee </kid>
   </dad>
</root>
```

My goal is to replace `<dad>` by `<mom>` but keeping the kid information.

Ive tryed

`xml.XPathSelectElements("dad")`

then looping over and

`dad.ReplaceWith(new XElement("mom", dad.descendants());`

but it doesnt work :(

Any ideas on how to do this ?

Comment: I feel you have a few options, such as copying the children to a new collection with the correct element hierarchy, though if it's all elements of <dad> that you want to change, I'd parse the xml to string,  .Replace() then parse back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to rename the element 'dad' to 'mom':

```
xml.Root.Elements("dad").ToList().ForEach(d => d.Name = "mom");
```

If 'mom' is an existing element with its own elements and attributes i would replace the 'dad'-element and add the 'kid'-element to the 'mom' element:

```
xml.Root.Elements("dad").ToList().ForEach(d =>
{
    XElement mom = new XElement("mom"); //use your mom here
    mom.Add(d.Descendants());
    d.ReplaceWith(mom);
});
```